# Zoom to a specific pyqgis layer

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis

I am trying to zoom in a specific layer but I have not succeeded. He tried several answers but it doesn't work for me.

This is my code

```
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
import os

fn8=rutas[2]
fn8=fn8.rstrip()
fn8=fn8+"\Datos Puntos Qgis.shp"
fn8=fn8.rstrip()
layer6 = QgsVectorLayer(fn8, 'ObrasCiviles', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer6) # Lo añado al mapa de capas


QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer6.id()).setExpanded(False)

layer6 = iface.activeLayer ()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas ()
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas ()
canvas.zoomToSelected (layer6)
canvas.refresh ()
```

Either it gives me a mistake or it does nothing to me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should select all the objects in the layer before doing this:

```
   layer6.selectAll()
   canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
   canvas.zoomToSelected(layer6)
   layer6.removeSelection()
```

Taken from here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108978/zooming-to-layer-extent-in-pyqgis

Answer (score 0):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()  # or whatever layer you want
extent = layer.extent()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```